# How to specify different FTP user in deployment credentials for each Azure Website?

Tags: azure, ftp

I am trying to setup FTP access for the Azure website.I have added a user in the deployment credentials for an Azure website.Which is fine,but the same credentials are replicated to all the remaining websites in my subscription.
Is there any way to adding a user for only a specific website?
Or Can we delete the user from a specific website?
How to specify different deployment users for each Azure website?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No!

The deployment credentials are bound to your Microsoft Account (Live ID) and are same for all the web sites that your account has access to. These are called `user level credentials`.

There is also `site level credentials` - this are auto generated and auto managed by the KUDU. You cannot change it to a value of your own. Usually it is a long long string for username and same for password.

You can learn more about Web Site Credentials at the [WIKI page for the KUDU project](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials). What is KUDU? KUDU is the project that runs Azure Web Sites.

My understanding about your concern is that you want to give out FTP access to a 3rd party, and you don't want them to have access to the rest of the Web Sites you have. Well, currently this is partially possible - only with the Site-Level credentials, over which you have no control (username / password).

Comment: Thanks,So using **site level credentials** for azure websites we can provide 3rd party acess for a single website.

Comment: If you have carefully read the 1 page long text I provided, you would have found the paragraph regarding site-level credentials: "They can also be useful when a subscription owner wants to allow an external party to publish to just one site while having no access to the others."

Comment: As you said user level credentials are bound to live id associated,Is it possible to provide different user level credentials  for different websites by logging in as a different co-administrator.